# "Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades" at the end of apt-get. How can I fix this?

Tags: apt, server, raspberrypi, 21.04, microcode

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 Server on Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB RAM)

When I use apt to install a package, I get some messages at the end that I don't remember getting on my PC:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Scanning processes...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...
Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
```

I am concerned about the message "Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades."

Why could it be failing? How can I fix this?

Comment: This can also occur in the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) where you've run a "do-release-upgrade" and the module has been installed where it is not needed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All these messages [came](https://sources.debian.org/src/needrestart/3.5-4/needrestart/?hl=943#L943) from [`needrestart` application](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/needrestart) which purpose is

> check which daemons need to be restarted after library upgrades

This application have several modules. The processor microcode module [supports only AMD and Intel processors](https://sources.debian.org/src/needrestart/3.5-4/README.uCode.md/). So it knows nothing about ARM in the RaspberryPi, so it shows the mentioned error message.

If you do not want to get such messages, then remove this application by

```
sudo apt-get purge needrestart
```

or edit relevant configuration file at `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf` and disable microcode checks completely by changing

```
#$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;
```

to

```
$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Although I'm still worried about these packages that have dependency on needrestart(might break if I remove needrestart)
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache rdepends needrestart`
needrestart
Reverse Depends:
  needrestart-session
  ubuntu-server
  freedombox
  fbx-all
  aptitude-robot
  apt-dater-host
  unattended-upgrades
  ubuntu-server-raspi

Comment: See updated answer. You can use `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf` configuration file to disable ucode check.

Comment: Perfect! so if i disable processor microcode check nothing relevant will appen to my system?

Comment: Seems like removing the symptoms instead of fixing the issue